# How to Phrase an Induction Proof That Only Goes up to 100?

Tags: proof-writing, induction, article-writing

Say I have a statement $P(n)$ which is true for all natural numbers $1 \leq n \leq 100$, but is nonsensical or false for other values of $n$. If I want to prove that $P(n)$ is true for $1 \leq n \leq 100$, and it seems induction is the best option, I'll often use induction to prove the following statement:

**"For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, If $n \leq 100$, then $P(n)$."**

I have two concerns with this:

1. It adds awkward and tedious wording to the proof. For example, in the induction step, I'll say something like this: "Suppose for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ that if $k \leq 100$, then $P(k)$. Now suppose $k+1 \leq 100$. It follows that $k \leq 100$, so we have $P(k)$..."
2. Sometimes $P(101)$ is not simply false, but undefined, so the bolded statement of the second paragraph is meaningless. I feel weird including a meaningless statement in a proof.

Am I right to be troubled by this? If so, is there any phrasing I can use to accomplish such a proof while avoiding these issues?

Comment: Induction is a method designed to prove infinitely many statements.  It is rarely a good idea to use it to prove $100$ statements.

Comment: You can just say, "Assume $n<100$ and that $P(n)$ is true."  Then you prove $P(n+1).$    You don't need any conditions on $n$ in the induction hypothesis.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks, this is just what I needed. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Vadim123.  I certainly dsagree.  If the way to prove it is to shunt from one value to another there is utterly no problem with the lengthy queue being finite.

Comment: @vadim123: I... cannot comprehend that line of thinking. It is pretty rare for someone to prefer writing 100 separate proofs rather than a single induction proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just say, "Assume $n<100$ and that $P(n)$ is true." Then you prove $P(n+1).$ You don't need any conditions on $n$ in the induction hypothesis.